# Cannot import pip installed package as non-root user

Tags: python, pip, centos

Unable to import a python module as a non root that was installed as root.

I have installed  `flask_babelex` package in both ways:

```
pip3 install --user flask_babelex
pip3 install flask_babelex
```

and working fine when I try to `import`:

```
[root@dev-apache ~]# python3 -c "import flask_babelex"
```

It's not working if were I run as a non-root user:

```
[root@dev-apache ~]#  su - apache
-bash-4.2$
-bash-4.2$ python3 -c "import flask_babelex"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_babelex'
```

I tried by changing permission to `site-packages` but no use:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

any workaround suggestions?

Comment: Check with this command `which python3`, Most probably, it will be two different python3 installations. That would be the problem.

Comment: I checked the path there no issue with it. `[root@dev-apache ~]# which python3
/bin/python3`

Comment: How about `which python` from the non-root terminal?

Comment: `[apache@dev-apache ~]# which python /bin/python`.

Comment: Finally, it's working. it seems a permission issue. I changed permission as  `chmod 777 -R /usr/local/lib/python3.6`,`chmod 777 -R /usr/local/lib/python2.7`. But, I'm not sure this is the right way or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure you're installing the package with the correct python environment by running

```
python3 -m pip install flask_babelex
```

This will install the package specifically in the environment that your `python3` is using